# WPF: Viewport3D (C#) inside a Canvas (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewport3d

I'm a beginner in WPF, so I don't understand exactly how C# works with XAML to make the application.

I'm trying to make a software to draw and manipulate 3D geometry. I've followed [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-3-d-scene) on how to create a 3D scene and was succesful.

But, when I try to put the `Viewport3D` inside a `canvas` in XAML (so that I can place other elements like buttons in the UI to manipulate the 3D scene), I can't figure out why the `Viewport3D` doesn't show up.

I don't want to define everything of the `Viewport3D` in XAML because I plan to have more complex operations of drawing and manipulation of geometry. And I think it is better to do it in C#.

The MainWindow from the C# file isn't the same on the XAML file?

Here is the window I get:

[image]

Here is the code:

XAML

```
<Window x:Name="Geology3D_MainWindow" x:Class="Geology3D.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Geology3D"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Geology3D" Height="600" Width="800" Background="Silver">
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas3D" Background="White" Margin="10,29,16.6,7.4">
        <Viewport3D x:Name="ViewPort3D">

        </Viewport3D>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Geology3D
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Viewport3D ViewPort3D = new Viewport3D();

            Model3DGroup ModelsGroup = new Model3DGroup();
            ModelVisual3D GModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();

            GeometryModel3D CubeGeometryModel = new GeometryModel3D();
            GeometryModel3D PlaneGeometryModel = new GeometryModel3D();

            PerspectiveCamera Camera = new PerspectiveCamera();

            // Specify where in the 3D scene the camera is.
            Camera.Position = new Point3D(-5, 5, -5);

            // Specify the direction that the camera is pointing.
            Camera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(1, -1, 1);

            // Asign the camera to the viewport
            ViewPort3D.Camera = Camera;

            // Define the lights cast in the scene. Without light, the 3D object cannot 
            // be seen. Note: to illuminate an object from additional directions, create 
            // additional lights.
            DirectionalLight GDirectionalLight = new DirectionalLight();
            GDirectionalLight.Color = Colors.White;
            GDirectionalLight.Direction = new Vector3D(-1, -1, -1);

            ModelsGroup.Children.Add(GDirectionalLight);

            // The material specifies the material applied to the 3D object.
            // Define material and apply to the mesh geometries.
            DiffuseMaterial BlueMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue));
            DiffuseMaterial PlaneMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray));

            CubeGeometryModel.Material = BlueMaterial;
            PlaneGeometryModel.Material = PlaneMaterial;

            // Apply the mesh to the geometry model.
            CubeGeometryModel.Geometry = DrawCube();
            PlaneGeometryModel.Geometry = DrawPlane();

            // Apply a transform to the object. In this sample, a rotation transform is applied,  
            // rendering the 3D object rotated.
            RotateTransform3D GRotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D();
            AxisAngleRotation3D GAxisAngleRotation3d = new AxisAngleRotation3D();
            GAxisAngleRotation3d.Axis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
            GAxisAngleRotation3d.Angle = 0;
            GRotateTransform3D.Rotation = GAxisAngleRotation3d;
            CubeGeometryModel.Transform = GRotateTransform3D;

            // Add the geometry model to the model group.
            ModelsGroup.Children.Add(CubeGeometryModel);
            ModelsGroup.Children.Add(PlaneGeometryModel);

            // Add the group of models to the ModelVisual3d.
            GModelVisual3D.Content = ModelsGroup;

            ViewPort3D.Children.Add(GModelVisual3D);
        }

        MeshGeometry3D DrawCube()[...]

        MeshGeometry3D DrawPlane()[...]

    }
}
```

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate, Canvas items need their Width and Height set explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @MarkFeldman, I've seen the question you marked before, but I might have missed something when I've tried the solution given there. Setting Width and Height solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is to overlay UI elements it might be easier to nest the canvas and the Viewport3D in a grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Viewport3D>
    ...
    </Viewport3D>
    <Canvas/>
</Grid>
```

This way the viewport and the canvas will always have the same size and elements added to the canvas will always be on top.

Comment: I've tried just nesting the canvas and the viewport3D inside a grid, but without setting the viewport3D position and size, nothing happens.

Comment: @MarcosSaito - The Grid will size the Viewport3D. This should be fine. Without your xaml it is hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, now I understood what you said. I've tried to nest the Viewport3D inside the Canvas, and then the Canvas inside the Grid. And you told me to nest the ViewPort3D inside the grid, and the Canvas above the Viewport3D, inside the Grid too. Thanks.